# How to use multiple threads while sending multiple requests to the server?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am working on an iOS app where user is able to store a location(place, building etc.) on his favourites list. This list is stored on a MySQL database and through HTTP REQUEST I am able to retrieve and display them on the Map. In addition, user's favourite locations are stored on the device, `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`. However, because user may have removed a location from his list, I have to double-check each location (stored in the device) if still exist in database. Here, I have to mention that, once user has logon, app stores his info (downloads favourite locations and store them in device) and the next time, user logon automatically. The user is able to remove any personal details from the specific device using 'Remove Account'. All location are stored in the device as a 'comma delimiter' file.

My question is, how I can improve my app's speed while is reading every single building and 1) checking if included in user's stored list 2) included in user's database list. At the moment, my map stays freeze(small squares) until finish the above procedure and then load the map and move to user's current location. I have a freeze time approx. 4-5 seconds.

I have tried to call the method who is responsible to,
"read each location from the file > check if exist inside user's stored favourite list > (if yes) check if still exist in user's favourite list on database > (if yes) add annotation > (else) remove it from stored list [remove object]"
using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        //call method
});
```

but still the delay is around 03.7 - 04.9 seconds

I am using `dispatch_get_global_queue` wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest starting out with time profiling on Instruments. That will help you understand the major bottleneck of the process

Comment: There's nothing wrong is your invocation of `dispatch_get_global_queue`, as long as you're not doing any UI updates inside that block. Any UI updates need to be dispatched back to the main queue. There's not enough here to let us diagnose the issue.

Comment: Hello @Rob, no I don't have any UI updates inside that method. I am just clearing the array of annotations, store new annotations, according current location and at the end addAnnotations on the map. The rest happen in main thread.

Comment: @Stavash I have never used time profiling before. What's this about? How I can figure out the problem?

Comment: It gives good indication as to what methods are taking up most of your computing time. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments/

Comment: Wow! I will have a look. Thanks

Comment: Also see [WWDC 2012 - #211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211).